# API references for JavaScript, DOM, HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html

1. [IE JS 9 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1et7k7c%28v=VS.94%29.aspx)
2. [Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs)
3. [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action)
4. [Opera](http://www.opera.com/developer/)

The above are JS API/DOM/HTML/CSS reference for the different browsers.

However i am having tough time finding the API reference for Google Chrome.

Please help me with that. I am looking for HTML5 API's reference for different browsers . Also in case there is better resource that this that will be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Chrome it is called "Chrome Extensions"...

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The following page contains the documentation for the WebKit layout engine, the engine used by Safari, but also by Google Chrome and other browsers:
[Webkit DOM Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/Canvas.html).

A list of the different layout engines, the browsers they are used in, and also links to the documentation for the different engines can be found [on this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5_Canvas%29).